# How to load & save custom object to iOS and OSX?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a custom object that's used in both an iOS app and an OSX app. It look like this:

```
@interface Preset : NSObject

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *customThumbnail;
#else
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSImage *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSImage *customThumbnail;
#endif

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *parms;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

I want the object to be able to be loaded and saved in both iOS and OSX wherever I created it.

I was going to implement the NSCoding methods for simple loading and saving, but then it occurred to me that I wouldn't be able to create a Preset file on OSX and use it in iOS because of the differences between NSImage and UIImage.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I don't see it.

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: ... Use actual images?

Comment: Don't include the images in your file, but make them separate jpg files or whatever they originally are.  (This is much more compact than the UIImages anyway.)

Comment: Use the NSData representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `UIImage` or `NSImage` to `NSData` containing the PNG representation of the image. Then use that `NSData` in your `NSCoding` setup.